# Logical OR order of operations/precedence not as expected

Tags: ruby

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Logical_Or

> The binary "or" operator will return the logical disjunction of its
>   two operands. **It is the same as "||" but with a lower precedence**

As I understand it, as || has a higher precedence than "or", the code below will first test if 'b' is true, then 'c', and then if both are false will test 'a'. I would like to witness this but am not sure if my understanding is incorrect, or simply my test.

```
a = true
b = false
c = false
p a or b || c
==> true #but were b and c checked as expected?
```

My attempt to test this is as follows..

```
def atest
  a = "string a"
  a.include? 'string'
  a
end

def btest
  b = "string b"
  b.include? 'string'
  b
end

def ctest
  c = "string c"
  c.include? 'string'
  c
end

puts "#{atest or btest || ctest}"
==> string a
```

I expected 'string b' to be returned... I'm completely new to programming since a week ago so I'm not sure, is my code wrong or is my understanding of the quote wrong?

edit: Appreciation on its own seems to be discouraged in responses, so I'll hide it here. Cheers for all the answers/further reading/code cleanup, it's clear now where I was going wrong.

Comment: `a || b && c` will evaluate `a` in the first place as well. Precedence matters if and only we are talking about _operations themselves_. Operands are evaluated from left to right in any case.

Comment: You are much better off using brackets `()` for explicit precedence than mixing `||` and `or` in the same expression. Otherwise it will be much harder to debug your code.

Comment: Simple rule: don't use ```and``` and ```or``` for logical operations.

Comment: @pascalbetz: better rule: don't use and/or ever. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev which might be a bit hard for logical operation?

Comment: @pascalbetz: huh? What you mean?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev misunderstood your comment, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, `&&`, `and`, `||`, and `or` are [short-circuit operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

> [...] the second argument is executed or evaluated only if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression: when the first argument of the `AND` function evaluates to `false`, the overall value must be `false`; and when the first argument of the `OR` function evaluates to `true`, the overall value must be `true`.

In your example:

```
a or b || c
```

Ruby evaluates `a`, sees a *truthy* value and immediately returns it, without evaluating `b || c`.

`or`'s lower precedence means that the expression is evaluated as:

```
a or (b || c)
```

instead of:

```
(a or b) || c
```

Just like

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

is evaluated as:

```
1 + (2 * 3)
```

because `+` has lower precedence than `*`.

But it doesn't change the order of evaluation. `1` is still evaluated before `2 * 3`.

Also note that due to `or`'s very low precedence

```
p a or b || c
```

is evaluated as:

```
(p a) or (b || c)
```

Neither `b` nor `c` will ever be printed this way.

Further readings:

- [Using “and” and “or” in Ruby](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)
- [How to use Ruby’s English and/or operators without going nuts](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/)
- [Ruby: On The Perl Origins Of “&&” And “||” Versus “and” And “or”.](http://www.prestonlee.com/2010/08/04/ruby-on-the-perl-origins-of-and-versus-and-and-or/)

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote*: In your code there are lines that basically do nothing: `a.include? 'string'` is silently returning `truthy`, having no impact at all on the running code. These three functions might be rewritten as:

```
def atest
  "string #{__callee__[0]}"
end
alias :btest :atest
alias :ctest :atest
```

You are confusing operator precedence with normal execution flow. Operator precedence is about what operation to execute in advance when we have two operations applied to the same operand. Otherwise, the execution order is left-to-right. E.g.

```
a + b * c
```

is executed as:

```
a
b
# oh! ambiguity: lookup the precedence table: will do multiplication
c # (otherwise a + b)
*
+
```